# Drupal Commerce: View that displays orders with discontinued products

Tags: views, commerce

I've been working on this issue for most of the day and haven't found a solution. Has anyone ever set up a View in Drupal Commerce to display the orders that contain discontinued products?

I need a way to display the orders that have discontinued products, and also display which product in the order is discontinued.

I tried several Views plugins but I'm only able to look at orders, or discounted products. Not both at the same time.

Thoughts?

Comment: I've never used Dupal commerce, but I know views very well. Consider this a shot in the dark. Can you FILTER by discontinued? Are you able to add a RELATIONSHIP of discontinued? Perhaps is not called discontinued, maybe it has a name of "status" or something similar, which has discontinued inside of it.

Comment: Yep. You were actually right on the money. It wasn't called Discontinued. Someone changed the label to say something else. I had never seen that before in Commerce and thought there was a contrib module that added it. Doh! Thank you for your help!